# Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server in Docker image

Tags: python, docker

I created image in Docker with Dockerfile:

```
# Write your dockerfile code here
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
USER root

# Upgrade version of pip to avoid warning message
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y
# clean the install.

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /
COPY requirements/core.txt .

# Install the application's Python packages
ARG PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL_GAR
RUN pip install --extra-index-url "${PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL_GAR}"  -r core.txt

# Set environment and timezone
# ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/app/config/adc.json"
ENV TZ=America/Toronto
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

COPY . .
# Entrypoint to run the app
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["Tableau_export.py"]
```

However, I am receiving error like this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

I was trying to resolve it by adding lines with Adding SQL Server ODBC Driver 18 for Ubuntu 18.04 but probably I do it incorrectly and also receiving errors :(

Comment: which lines did you try to add and what errors do you get?

Comment: I added:
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
  && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated msodbcsql18 mssql-tools \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

But still receiving similar error